# Как сделать дозвон, скажем после 30 секунд бросить трубку автоматически без действий пользователя?

Tags: android

[В продолжении темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610011/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/874144#874144)

Задача довольно простая.

Создаете BroadcastReceiver, который будет перехватывать набранные номера:

```
public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // получаем набранный номер
        String mOutgoingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        if (mOutgoingNumber.equals("##007*#*")) {
             setResultData(null); // сбрасываем звонок

             //  другие необходимые вам действия при наборе нужного номера

        }        
    }
}
```

Регистрируем ресивер на срабатывание при наборе исходящего номера (интент NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) и даем необходимые разрешения на контроль исходящих звонков (пермишен PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS) в манифесте приложения.

```
AndroidManifest.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.outgoingmanager.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".OutgoingReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

А как сделать чтобы вызов отменялся скажем после 30 секунд? Нужно дать гудок и сбросить. Я пробовал таймер не срабатывает, а если просто поставить в коде TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30); перед setResultData(null); То тогда приложение просто виснет, выходит на телефоне ошибка что приложение повисло типа подождать или ок и телефон продолжает звонить не сбрасывается. Или может есть какой-либо другой способ?

Вызов делаю так :

```
            String posted_by = "+7905.......";
            String uri = "tel:" + posted_by.trim();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Эту задачу можно решить через TelephonyManager.
Для начала нужно добавить еще два пермишена CALL_PHONE и READ_PHONE_STATE.
Создать новый пакет com.android.internal.telephony возле пакета приложения то есть не внутри com.test.outgoingmanager.app а на том же уровне.
Внутри пакета создаем файл ITelephony.aidl с следующим содержанием

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;

public interface ITelephony {      

  boolean endCall();     

  void answerRingingCall();      

  void silenceRinger(); 

}
```

Далее получаем ссылку на TelephonyManager и в ход идет рефлексия

```
try{
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)        
    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) 
    m.invoke(tm);  
    telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
    telephonyService.endCall();
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Также текущим способом можно отвечать на звонки и прочие вещи.
Код не проверял если не сработает то вот пару ссылок.

http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580508/how-to-import-com-android-internal-telephony-itelephony-to-the-android-applicati